# Autocomplete does not appear in view, ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have one field in my view, it is a textbox field. But I'd like to change that field to an Autocomplete dropdown.

Below is my view:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SearchFilterPaymentCode, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "searchInput1" })
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#searchInput1").autocomplete({
         source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
               url: '@Url.Action("getJenisPembayaran", "Payment1")',
               dataType: "json",
                 data: {
                      term: request.term
                 },
                 success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (val, item) {
                      return {
                          label: val.Name,
                          value: val.Name,
                          ID: val.ID
                      }
                    }))
                 }
            })
         },
         select: function (event, ui) {
            $("#ID").val(ui.item.ID);
            $("#SearchFilterPaymentCode").val(ui.item.label);
         }
      });
    })
</script>
```

and below is my controller

```
public JsonResult getJenisPembayaran(string term)
{
    var objCustomerlist = db.ParamJenisPembayarans.Where(x => x.Name.ToUpper()
                                .Contains(term.ToUpper()))
                                .Select(x => new ParamJenisPembayaranViewModel
                                {
                                    ID = x.ID,
                                    JenisPembayaran = x.Name
                                }).Distinct().ToList();
    return Json(objCustomerlist, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

When I debug the controller and fill the textbox with a few words, I get some data from the database, that means the controller is working well but the data does not appear in the view. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: which js library are you using?

Comment: I'm using jquery @FatikhanGasimov

Comment: Can you see a response for `getJenisPembayaran` in your dev console network tab?

Comment: I type getJenisPembayaran on console using chrome and get this error "Uncaught ReferenceError: getJenisPembayaran is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1" @PriyankPanchal

Comment: Keep your devtools --> network tab open and try to use the autocomplete textbox. You will see it hitting your `getJenisPembayaran` method. Select that row and check the Response tab to see what you are receiving back from the server.

Comment: I have done it,  and got two data. 
but it doesn't appear in Texbox @PriyankPanchal

Comment: and I look at the tab element, autocomplete is OFF, and I set it to ON but still doesn't appear in the textbox @PriyankPanchal